# Should std::vectors be used extensively for embedded systems?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl, embedded

When writing C++ code for an embedded system with limited CPU and Memory resources, the common rule of thumb is to instantiate objects in the stack, and avoid using the heap unless it is really necessary.  Doing this of course has many known benefits, but with the emergence of STL and folks recommending std::vectors as an efficient data structure, does it violate the rule of thumb that I mentioned, since the vector will be using the heap?

Example:  In the old days, one would declare static arrays with known sizes that will satisfy the usage. Nowadays, one would just use vectors.

I'm not really comfortable with this transition, since there is always a possibility of the vector failing to allocate the required memory (reminder: this is for embedded systems with limited memory). Using arrays with known sizes in the stack guarantees that there will be space for allocation during compile-time.

Calling reserve() kind of helps, but this is done during run-time.

So, is this a cause for concern, or am I just being paranoid?  It's definitely much more easier to use these vectors, but for an embedded environment, it might not be a good idea?

**Note:** This is not about dynamic vs fixed arrays, but more on how the data is allocated in memory, which is a big deal for my environment. As an example, some folks would do this: Say the array can grow or shrink between 1 to 10 elements. Some folks would create an array that covers this size in the stack, and NULL terminate depending on current size. This way, fragmentation is avoided, and we are guaranteed allocation during compile time.  However, switching to vector made it much more cleaner, but at the expense of using the heap, and potentially having to deal with exceptions if allocation fails. This is what I am concerned about.

Comment: If you know how many items will be in the vector (or at least a rough estimate) you can then `reserve` space for the data.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with a static or automatic array, if the size is known at compile time and you make sure the stack is big enough. Use `vector` when you specifically want a dynamic array. (These days, you can use `std::array` to make a fixed-size array look more STL-like, if you want.)

Comment: There's no general answer to this question. You may or may not run into a bottleneck caused by standard vector on an embedded system. One can only decide whether to use it after performing a proper benchmark on a particular piece of code running on a particular system.

Comment: Stacks can blow just like heaps can be full.

Comment: "Limited CPU and memory resources" means something different today than when rules of thumb like that were created.  It depends on how limited your hardware really is. If you have memory measured in tens or hundreds of bytes and CPU speeds measured in kHz, then those rules still stand, but if you have megabytes of RAM and gigahertz of cycles, then you can often avoid worrying about optimization.

Comment: Kristopher Johnson, I beg to differ. The hardware that I am working on has 32MB of memory, and adhering to rule of thumbs enabled us to maintain this spec without having to create new hardware. With new programmers joining, the sudden surge in memory usage per feature dramatically increased.

Answer (score 10):

I believe that you have forgotten one very important property of the STL containers: *allocators*.

A STL container (whether a `vector` or otherwise) obtain all its memory from its allocator (apart from the very basic stack footprint that you can check with `sizeof`). Therefore, it is perfectly suitable in embedded development to provide a dedicated allocator that:

- will allocate from a pre-reserved memory area
- will bound the maximum resource consumption to prevent OOM
- ...

With the advent of C++11, you may even use stateful allocators, so that a single allocator type can point to different pools of memory.

Therefore, the use of `std::vector`, or even `std::set` or `std::map`, is not incompatible with a pre-allocation strategy; do remember though that apart from `std::vector` other STL containers generally have some per-item overhead which must be taken into account when sizing the memory area they should draw upon.

Comment: Thanks, Matt. I'll look into allocators.

Comment: Seems like whatever dynamic allocation method you use, whether heap, 'allocators', or stack, if you exceed your compile-time defined memory you will need to manage the situation where you run out of memory. Catching exceptions is not difficult. The difficult thing is to design fail-safe or robust responses to out-of-memory errors.  For an embedded system with associated risks/hazards I'd recommend sticking with fixed-size arrays.

Comment: @Dana: There is no difference between a fixed-size array and a vector here; in either case you need to compute (and validate) the maximum amount of memory that will be required, and ensure it is there.

Answer (score 4):

"Depends" may be an understatement here. By using reserve with vectors, you can efficiently allocate space for the data and prevent unnecessary copies. The vector data structure itself will boil down to a heap allocated array with a size if the compiler is good enough.

Also, note I said *heap*. If you would rather allocate the data to the stack, your stuck with fixed sized arrays (including std::array).

And it also depends heavily on the compiler how vector is put together. Older compilers may (big emphasis on may) be less efficient. This is why for embedded systems you really need to know the architecture and compiler before making sweeping generalizations about what is "good" and what is "bad" to use.

Answer (score 3):

> Using arrays with known sizes in the stack guarantees that there will be space for allocation during compile-time.

**Wrong assumption.**

When your got a lot of call (not even recursive but a stack with a lot of level), you cannot be sure that there is enough space for your stack to hold the object that have to be created on.

There are basic checks (if the size of your object exceed size_t at least), but I do not even think they are made mandatory by the standard.

A -- somewhat excessive -- example is here:

```
#include <iostream>

template <unsigned long size>
struct BigObject
{
    unsigned long array[size * size];
    BigObject<size - 1> object;
};


template <>
struct BigObject<0>
{
    unsigned long array[1]; 
};

BigObject<900>& recurse(BigObject<900>& object1, unsigned long n)
{
    if (n == 0)
    {
        return object1;
    }

    BigObject<900> object;

    return recurse(object, n);
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    BigObject<900> object;
    recurse(object, 20);

    std::cout << sizeof(object) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/pkHo43

It does crash.
And it is not such a special case. I had the problem in a 32 bit desktop oriented application  (so none of your memory constraint) allocating a too big array on the stack.

Comment: If the object/array is global, isn't it guaranteed?

Comment: Yes, it is guaranteed by th elinker. You have to check but I think you cannot make a program run out of memory if it use only objects stored in .data segment (unless you cannot load the library itself)

Comment: Although you can get tools which measure the possible call chains, and calculate the maximum stack depth necessary (or, at least, you could - they are probably less useful with languages that support recursion).

Answer (score 2):

`std::vector` should be used for dynamically resized arrays. If you know the size at compile time, you can use `std::array` instead.

If you know the only approximate size of array, **since C++14** you may use `std::dynarray`. This array has fixed size which cannot be changed during object lifetime. When the `std::dynarray` without allocator is used additional optimisations are possible, the `operator new` may not be called and stack-based allocation will be used.

Comment: Some folks would do this: Say the array can grow or shrink between 1 to 10 elements. Some folks would create an array that covers this size in the stack, and NULL terminate depending on current size. Switching to vector is much cleaner, but at the expense of using the heap. This is what I am concerned about

Comment: Cool, I'll look into std::dynarray.  Thanks!

Comment: @Ryuu note that `std::dynarray` is available only since C++14.

Answer (score 1):

A `std::vector` is just a pointer and two `size_t` when compiled with sufficient optimization flags. Now the memory for the `size_t` is a waste when your know the size of the vector in advance and it will never change.

I would say:

- Fixed (small) size => simple array or [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)
- Dynamic size or huge number of elements => [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

And as mentioned in the comments, you can use most of the functionality of e.g. [`<algorithms>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) on fixed size arrays by using pointers for the `begin`/`end` iterators.

For example:

```
int array[8] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 };
std::random_shuffle(array, array+8);
```

Comment: It's two pointers and a `size_t`, or equivalently (but AFAIK rarer in practice) a pointer and two `size_t`s. And it's not just about the size of the vector itself, the fact that its memory is allocated dynamically has consequences: There's allocator overhead (both in time and space), and there's the risk of fragmentation.

Comment: Why is there the risk of fragmentation? `vector` stores its elements in continuous memory.

Comment: Well, other STL functionality is the reason for the transition. Examples include sorting, finding, etc without having to re-implement them. I know the STL's sort will work for arrays as well, but in general, STL provided much more functionality (or reduced the need to re-invent the wheel)

Comment: In an embedded system, you may want to include the use of vector to lower stack usage, especially on recursive function calls.

Comment: @Ryuu Before you refactor all your code, you know you can use std::sort, ect on pointers of contiguous memory as well, right?

Comment: Danvil, although vector elements are contiguous, every push_back would/might cause a reallocation of memory to fit the new size. If the next block of memory is occupied, it needs to find somewhere else. Doesn't this cause fragmentation?

Comment: MadScienceDreams, yup, like I mentioned, I know they work for pointers as well. I'll try to see if other things like find() can work that way as well.